# Can't obtain the items array in Firebase analytics when using logEvent

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using the firebase logEvent function on web according to this [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events)

What I have done
Firstly, I have init the firebase

```html
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "Xxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "Xxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "Xxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "Xxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "Xxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "Xxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "Xxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

and then i use the log event method just like the example shown on the website

```html
analytics.logEvent('select_content', {
  content_type: 'image',
  content_id: 'P12453',
  items: [{ name: 'Kittens' }]
});
```

On the firebase analytics dashboard,
I receive the following parameters

1. `content_id`
2. `content_type`
3. `debug_mode`
4. `engagement_time_msec`
5. `ga_session_id`
6. `ga_session_number`
7. `origin`
8. `page_location`
9. `page_title`

but i can't find the items
How can I find my items parameters ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked firebase support , they give me an answer

> It seems that your trying to use the ITEMS parameter for select_content event. Do note that this is not possible as you can only use ITEMS parameter on all predefined Ecommerce events.

So you need to follow the documentation about setting up predefined Ecommerce events , [link here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9268036?hl=en&visit_id=637580364802073639-17757106&rd=1).